# ¿Cómo gestiona bootstrap el ancho de las columnas de una tabla?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Cuando empleas tablas con bootstrap, normalmente se establece el ancho de columna de forma automática, muchas veces el ancho es exagerado en comparación con la longitud del texto que contiene, sé que se puede poner un ancho fijo o un ancho máximo para solucionar el problema, pero, ¿de donde salen las anchuras de columna que bootstrap pone por defecto a una tabla cuando no especificas nada?

PD: Espero que los usuarios del foro entiendan la pregunta sin haber puesto código y no haya que corregir la pregunta porque no se entiende...

Comment: Depende de cómo hayas definido las celdas de tu tabla. ¿Has leído acerca del Grid System de Bootstrap? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Si, sé que puedo ponerle las clases del grid a las th de las tablas. Lo que quiero saber es qué criterio se usa cuando no se especifica nada.

Comment: No es cosa de Bootstrap  sino de un cálculo que hacen los navegadores para determinar el ancho de las celdas: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#width-layout

Answer (score 1):

He cojido una tabla de bootstrap para que podamos ver el funcionamiento:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">First</th>
                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Como podemos ver introduce un "scope=col" en cada th para saber que es una columna dentro de nuestra tabla.

Si pulsamos F12 desde Google Chrome abriremos la consola y podremos ver, seleccionando el th, el estilo predefinido que da bootstrap a sus columnas dentro de una tabla.

[image: Ver imagen de la consola de Google Chrome]

Aquí te muestro con mas detalle los estilos predefinidos de bootstrap.
[image: Estilos predefinidos de bootstrap.]

Como podemos ver le introduce un padding al "td" y al "th" de la tabla en base al porcentaje del ancho de tu pantalla. `padding=0.75em`.

Espero que la información que te proporciono sea la correcta.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Gonzalo, bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a [answer] y hacer el [tour]. Me temo que tu respuesta no responde del todo a la pregunta. Si te fijas verás con las herramientas de desarrollador que la anchura que indicas en el pantallazo (189px) no es la misma que la que aperece en el código que has puesto (snippet) ya que depende de la anchura del contenedor.

Comment: Buenas Kiko, como bien has dicho las dimensiones no son las mismas por el contenedor que utiliza SOes, pero como podemos ver le introduce un padding al "td" y al "th" de la tabla en base al porcentaje del ancho de tu pantalla. padding=0.75em. Un saludo.